# How to Recursively Multiply two positive integers without using the * operator (or / operator) ? . You can use addition, subtraction, and bit shifting

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I stumbled upon this solution, but I am not able to understand what exactly is happening in this. Can someone please explain!

From what I understand it is trying to count the number of cells in a*b grid by counting half the cells and then doubling it. But I am not able to understand the recursive calls.

Pleas don't suggest other solutions, try to explain this solution please :)

```
def minProduct(a,b):
    bigger = b if a < b else a #a < b ? b : a
    smaller = a if a < b else b #a < b ? a : b
    return minProductHelper(smaller,bigger)

def minProductHelper(smaller, bigger):
    if smaller == 0:
        return 0
    elif smaller == 1:
        return bigger

    # Compute half. If uneven, compute other half. If even, double it
    s = smaller >> 1 # divide by 2
    side1 = minProduct(s,bigger)
    side2 = side1
    if smaller % 2 == 1:
        side2 = minProductHelper(smaller - s, bigger)

    return side1 + side2

print(minProduct(5,6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm, in a sense. Bit shifting left by `1` effectively divides a number by `2` (discarding any remainder). `minProductHelper` divides `smaller` by `2` using `s = smaller >> 1` and then returns the recursively derived sum of `s * bigger` and `(smaller - s) * bigger`. Because of the properties of addition and multiplication, you have that `((smaller - s) * bigger) + (s * bigger) == smaller * bigger` which is the outcome you want. You have two base cases which are when `smaller` is either `0` or `1`, so you can imagine that a call to `minProduct(a,b)` will keep cutting `a` or `b` into halves (and those halves into halves, etc.) until all it has to do is sum a bunch of products involving `0` and some number or `1` and some number, which can be determined without having to use the `*` operator. The smaller number is always cut in half rather than the larger number because this allows the base cases to be reached with less recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are multiplying 5 and 6 together. Then the program first figures out the smallest number i.e. 5. It then calls itself by dividing the smallest number into two whole parts (nearly equal).

`minProduct(5,6)=minProduct(2,6)+minProduct(3,6)`. Then `minProduct(2,6)` is calculated similarly into  `minProduct(1,6)+minProduct(1,6)`. Now that the smaller number is one the program simply returns 6 and the values are calculated back.This happens to each function call.

`minProduct(5,6) =minProduct(2,6)+minProduct(3,6) =minProduct(1,6)+minProduct(1,6)+minProduct(3,6) (Let minProduct(3,6)=18) for cohesion) =6+6+18 =30`

**Why figure out the smallest number first?**
The previous answer deals with precisely why the smaller number was used instead of the larger number. Take two arbitrary numbers 2 and 1000. I need to figure out what 2*1000 is. It is easier to figure out 1000+1000 then (2+2+. ..+2). Less function calls means faster algorithm.

**Why was there a condition for minProduct(0,a)?**
You did see why there was a condition for minProduct(1,a). But there was a condition for minProduct(0,a) because there is a special case for multiplication by 2. When you call minProduct(2,3). This resolves to minProduct(2,3) and minProduct(0,3). So you need to handle this separately.